# Replace pair of % in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, replace, plsql

please, I have in Oracle table this texts (as 2 records)

`"Sample text with replace parameter %1%"
"You reached 90% of your limit"`

I need replace %1% with specific text from input parameter in Oracle Function. In fact, I can have more than just one replace parameters. I have also record with `"Replace this %12% with real value"`

This functionality I have programmed:

```
IF poc > 0 THEN
  FOR i in 1 .. poc LOOP
    p     := get_param(mString => mbody);
      mbody := replace(mbody,
      '%' || p || '%', parameters(to_number(p, '99')));
  END LOOP;
END IF;
```

But in this case I have problem with text number 2. This functionality trying replace "90%" also and I then I get this error:

`ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: NULL index table key value`

It's a possible to avoid try replace "90%"? Many thanks for advice.

Best regards

PS: Oracle version: 10g (OCI Version: 10.2)

Comment: Do you need to support multiple replacements, e.g. `No %1% exists for this %2%`?

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can work here. Try the following and build them into your script.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( 'Sample text with replace parameter %1%',
                   '\%[0-9]+\%',
                   'db_size' )
FROM   DUAL
```

and

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( 'Sample text with replace parameter 1%',
                   '\%[0-9]+\%',
                   'db_size' )
FROM   DUAL
```

The pattern is pretty simple; look for patterns where a '%' is followed by 1 or more numbers followed by a '%'.

The only issue here will be if you have more than one replacement to make in each string and each replacement is different. In that case you will need to loop round the string each time replacing the next parameter. To do this add the position and occurrence parameters to REGEXP_REPLACE after the replacement string, e.g.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( 'Sample text with replace parameter %88888888888%','\%[0-9]+\%','db_size',0,1 )
```

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the error because at `parameters(to_number(p, '99'))`. Can you please check the value of p?
Also, if the p=90 then then REPLACE will not try to replace "90%". It will replace "%90%". How have you been sure that it's trying to replace "90%"?

Comment: Please try to format code like described here https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-examples